# How do I start my grails dev server in single threaded mode?

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, grails

grails run-app will start my app in an embedded tomcat server.

I would like to configure this embedded server so that only a single request processor thread is available and that multiple threads are processed serially rather than concurrently (similar to default webrick behaviour in the rails world)

Is it possible? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: I do not believe that this is supported. Could be wrong ....

Comment: This is weird. I'm having the exact opposite problem. I'm trying to get grails run-app to run in multiple threads.

I have a controller that just does a loop and inside the loop it sleeps and spits out a log message containing a thread ID. I'm issuing two requests and I'm seeing one complete before the other one begins indicating that there's only a single request processor thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not directly supported by the Tomcat plugin. But you could easily modify the Tomcat plug-in and run your own version.

If you look at the class org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer, you will see it starts a Tomcat instance.
Here is the doc for this class: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html

There is a getConnector() method which will return the default HTTP connector. Once you have it, you can probably change the settings, like maxThreads.

But be careful the performance will be awful. But I guess you already know that.

Comment: You don't need to modify the plugin, just [implement `eventConfigureTomcat` in your `scripts/_Events.groovy`](http://roshandawrani.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/grails-tip-configuring-embedded-tomcat-instance-used-in-developmenttest-env/).